# Burninate request [ellipsis]

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

The [ellipsis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ellipsis) tag is absurdly broad, has 1 follower and [272 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ellipsis), with the tag wiki simply stating:

> An Ellipsis is a series of dots (usually 3) used to indicate the
>   omission of a word within some text, or more commonly that the
>   preceding text has been truncated.

If there is an argument for [ellipsis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ellipsis) to be made more specific then by all means, but by looking through the question list it appears to have little to no merit as a tag so should likely be killed *pronto*

Comment: But who doesn't love a good ...

Comment: Oh very droll...! *applause*

Comment: ...and over ten of those are either [duplicate] or [closed]. Probably many more dups if you took the time to investigate them.

Comment: Yeah... this isn't typography.stackexchange.com.

Comment: What does truncate have to do with ellipse?

Comment: @RobertHarvey - not clear from the question (my bad), there is a fair bit of crossover, e.g. truncating a string and appending an ellipsis as indication of that. But yes, they don't 1-1 relate

Comment: ...mentioning truncate perhaps muddies the waters here.

Comment: Not to mention the complete ambiguity of it, in Java, it's the varargs syntax, in Python it's a singleton object often used like `pass`. It seems like a tag about syntax as opposed to behavior is a bad idea, given it's inherently language-specific.